# VSCodeのRemote - WSLでWSL(Ubuntu)上のPythonを読み込んでデバッグしたい

Tags: python3, linux, ubuntu, vscode, wsl

[VSCode Remote WSLでPython開発環境構築](https://qiita.com/kayumi/items/184f9fcd0af16783967e)

上記ページを参考に、WSL1(Ubuntu)上のPython(pyenv + pipenv + flake8 + yapf)を読み込もうとしたのですが、以下の設定ファイルのように書いたところ、

```js
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "D:\\Users\\steel\\Documents\\Python_WSL"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {},
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python",
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.venv/**": true
    }
}
```

> 不明なワークスペース構成のプロパティ [8,5]
>   不明なワークスペース構成のプロパティ [9,5]

という警告が出ました。追加するコードを入れる場所を変えてみたりしたのですが、変わらず警告が出ます。
Pythonのインストールはpipenvを使ってpyenv経由でインストールしました。
flake8やyapfも読み込まれず、

```
Python is not installed. Please download and install Python before using the extension.
```

と出てPythonが認識されていないようです。
このエラー文で検索してみても、よくわかりませんでした。
この問題を解決、正しい、もしくは推奨される方法などあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくおねがいします。

**実行環境**
Windows 10 Home 1903
WSL1 Ubuntu
pyenv 1.2.13
pipenv 2018.11.26
entrypoints 0.3
flake8 3.7.8
mccabe 0.6.1
pycodestyle 2.5.0
pyflakes 2.1.1
yapf 0.28.0
pipenvコマンドでインストールしたPython 3.6.9
Visual Studio Code:
バージョン: 1.37.0 (system setup)
コミット: 036a6b1d3ac84e5ca96a17a44e63a87971f8fcc8
日付: 2019-08-08T02:33:50.993Z
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。
以下の設定で動くようになったので、解決とします。

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
$ sudo apt -y install python3-pip
$ sudo apt -y install gcc make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
$ echo '# pyenv' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ pip3 install --user pipenv
$ echo '# pipenv' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ pwd // 今いる場所を確認するためにやりました
$ mkdir pywork
$ cd pywork
$ pipenv install --python 3.6.9
$ pipenv install flake8
$ pipenv install yapf
```

```
{
    // Pythonのパス
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/username/pywork/.venv/bin/python",
    "python.venvPath": "/home/username/pywork/.venv",
    // flake8のパス
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "/home/username/pywork/.venv/bin/flake8",
    // yapfのパス
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/home/username/pywork/.venv/bin/yapf",
    // pylintの無効化
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    // flake8を有効化する
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    // フォーマットをyapfにする
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    // ファイルを保存するときにフォーマットをかける
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    }
}
```

---

この質問の解決策は私のQiitaとQrunchに環境含めて投稿します。ご了承ください。